# Unable to load my CSS during org-publish-project

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

I want to write an static website using `org-mode` and publish it from `emacs`.  For this, I followed [the tutorial](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html#orgd152350) I found in `org-mode` site.

My site directory tree is as follows:

```
~/org
    css/
      stylesheet.css
    index.org
```

My `org-publish-project-alist` looks as follows:

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(
        ("org-notes"
        :base-directory "~/org"
        :base-extension "org"
        :publishing-directory "~/public_html"
        :recursive t
        :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
        :headline-levels 4             ; Just the default for this project.
        :auto-preamble t
        )

        ("org-static"
        :base-directory "~/org"
        :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
        :publishing-directory "~/public_html"
        :recursive t
        :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
        )

        ("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))
        ))
```

I have not been able to link my `stylesheet.css` in the `index.html` generated.  This is how I tried to set the local variable `org-export-html-style` at the bottom of `index.org`

```
# Local Variables:
# org-export-html-style: "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" />"
# End:
```

What am I missing?

Comment: There is no variable called `org-export-html-style` any more. Maybe what you want is `org-html-head`? Or the in-file version in the answer by @jamesmaj?

Comment: The [tutorial](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.htm) is very old and probably contains a bunch of things that don't work any more. You might want to report this question as a bug to the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html).

Comment: I fixed two instances of obsolete variables in that tutorial, but if you find more, please report them to the mailing list.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the variables!  Although it is going to be hard to know what is obsolete without knowing org in depth, which is my case.

Comment: I understand and sympathize: there is a lot of old stuff that needs fixing on Worg, but the experienced people don't need the tutorials so they don't test them. That leaves the inexperienced ones to fall into all the potholes. All I can say is: complain loudly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line to the top of the org file:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/stylesheet.css" />
```

Reference: https://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html

Comment: Any idea how to make this automatic for all files in the project?

Comment: @ttb: you can put it in a <template>.org file  and use #+SETUPFILE: <template>.org in all files